# Text hover effect like knockout

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here I have a pen with tryimg to figure out the mistake.
Problem is cursor position is where the page is loaded. And I'm not able to make multiple effect for different links.
Also result I wanna achieve is same here:
    https://laerkeandersen.com/
Link to pen is here:
    https://codepen.io/Killrockstar/pen/VVNoMa

```
var cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

var short_headline = document.querySelector('#__short_headline');
var short_headline_position = short_headline.getBoundingClientRect();

var brand = document.querySelector('#__brand');
var brand_position = brand.getBoundingClientRect();

var sales = document.querySelector('#__sales');
var sales_position = sales.getBoundingClientRect();

var interdisciplinary = document.querySelector('#__interdisciplinary');
var interdisciplinary_position = interdisciplinary.getBoundingClientRect();

var menu_about = document.querySelector("a[href='/#about']");
var menu_about_position = menu_about.getBoundingClientRect();


document.body.onmousemove = function(e) {
    /*Adjust the position of the cursor*/
    cursor.style.left=e.pageX-20+'px';
    cursor.style.top=e.pageY-20+'px';
    /*Adjust the radial-gradient*/
    short_headline.style.setProperty('--x',(e.pageX-short_headline_position.left)+'px');
    short_headline.style.setProperty('--y',(e.pageY-short_headline_position.top)+'px');

    /*Adjust the position of the cursor*/
    /*Adjust the radial-gradient*/
    brand.style.setProperty('--x',(e.pageX-brand_position.left)+'px');
    brand.style.setProperty('--y',(e.pageY-brand_position.top)+'px');

    /*Adjust the position of the cursor*/
    /*Adjust the radial-gradient*/
    sales.style.setProperty('--x',(e.pageX-sales_position.left)+'px');
    sales.style.setProperty('--y',(e.pageY-sales_position.top)+'px');

    /*Adjust the position of the cursor*/
    /*Adjust the radial-gradient*/
    interdisciplinary.style.setProperty('--x',(e.pageX-interdisciplinary_position.left)+'px');
    interdisciplinary.style.setProperty('--y',(e.pageY-interdisciplinary_position.top)+'px');


    menu_about.style.setProperty('--x',(e.pageX-menu_about_position.left)+'px');
    menu_about.style.setProperty('--y',(e.pageY-menu_about_position.top)+'px');
}
```

Comment: When you say cursor position is where the page is loaded, what do you mean? The Codepen example looks to work fine for me

Comment: When you refresh page on the bottom, cursor is not on correct position. Also the navbar items are not with this effect. I think it's because script is catching cursor or blocks only from top position. But I don't know where to investigate it(